# Marketo Api Get Email Sent, Email Open And Email Clicked

Tags: marketo

As part of the project requirement I need to get the email opened, Email Sent and Email Clicked data from Marketo fpr a particular campaign. How can we acheive this. I looked in to the api but not able to find a suitable one.

Any help is appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use getLeadChanges (http://developers.marketo.com/documentation/soap/getleadchanges/) and listen for Open, Sent and Clicked. You'll get all info for all campaigns in the database for a particular timeframe. On your end, you'll have to filter out the responses for the campaign that you're interested in. There is also a similar API call for the REST API: http://developers.marketo.com/documentation/rest/get-lead-changes/

Answer (score 0):

As Jep mentioned, you would need to request all the data from Marketo's [Get Lead Activities REST API](http://developers.marketo.com/documentation/rest/get-lead-activities/) for these activities types, and then filter on your side. Here would be the steps to implement this:

**1. Generate Access Token**

Call [Marketo's Identity API](http://developers.marketo.com/documentation/rest/authentication/) with your client id and secret to generate an access token. Please see [Marketo's REST API quick start guide](http://developers.marketo.com/blog/quick-start-guide-for-marketo-rest-api/) for more information.

`<Identity Service URL>/oauth/token?grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=<custom_service_client_id>&client_secret=<custom_service_client_secret>`

**2. Call Get Paging Token API**

Requires your access token from step one, and desired start date. The [Get Paging Token API](http://developers.marketo.com/documentation/rest/get-paging-token/) will return a token that is needed for a request to [Get Lead Activities API](http://developers.marketo.com/documentation/rest/get-lead-activities/) in step three.

`/rest/v1/activities/pagingtoken.json?sinceDateTime=2014-10-06T13:22:17-08:00`

**3. Call Get Lead Activities API**

Requires your access token from step one and paging token from step two. You would need to specify the activityTypeIds for Email Opened, Email Sent and Email Clicked, which are activityTypeIds 10, 6, 11 respectively.

`/rest/v1/activities.json?nextPageToken=GIYDAOBNGEYS2MBWKQYDAORQGA5DAMBOGAYDAKZQGAYDALBQ&activityTypeIds=10&activityTypeIds=6&activityTypeIds=11`

**4. Filter**

Step three will return all activity data for the specified activity type and timeframe. The data will include an attribute for each record that specifies the particular campaign associated with it. You will then have to filter these records based on the campaign attribute.

Comment: This comment implies that activity type IDs are always consistent across subscriptions.  This isn't the case, however.  Activity type IDs may vary between subscriptions, so to determine the correct ID, Get Activity Types should be called: http://developers.marketo.com/documentation/rest/get-activity-types/

Comment: @Murtza how do you see retrieval of entire lead and its lead activities on daily basis use case. I have actually reached 60k leads in count and using SOAP/REST api is painfully slow. Even from dashboard I could get 100 results in batch. I am aware of API quota limits and API 20 sec windown between batches of 100.

Is there any other option to retrieve all leads and its lead activities at one shot?. 

I heard from Marketo support team that they are going to release a Bulk Export API, any thoughts anyone?